# Emerging package from overlay

Tags: linux, gentoo

I'm using gentoo, and I've been trying to emerge  [`leksah` package](http://gpo.zugaina.org/Overlays/haskell/app-editors/leksah) from `haskell` overlay:

```
root # layman -a haskell
root # layman -s haskell
root # emerge -av app-editors/leksah
```

However `emerge` keeps saying that

> there are no ebuilds to satisfy "app-editors/leksah".

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure `layman` appropriately so that portage searches your added overlays.

> **Option 1:  Using 'make.conf' method (older method)**
>
> `echo "source /var/lib/layman/make.conf" >> /etc/portage/make.conf`
>
> ...
>
> **Option 2: Using 'repos.conf' method (default method for app-portage/layman-2.3.0 or later)**
>
> Create /etc/portage/repos.conf/ directory, if it does not exist yet:
>
> `root #mkdir /etc/portage/repos.conf`
>
> If you have
>   app-portage/layman-2.3.0 or later installed, you can force a rebuild
>   of layman's repos.conf files:
>
> `root #layman-updater -R`

Source: [Layman - Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Layman#Configuration) (and for more details)

Comment: Note that in the layman documentation, it says `Installation of newer versions (>2.0.0, masked)`. That's "greater than" and not "greater than or equal to" as I first (incorrectly) interpreted it, and therefore followed the wrong directions for configuring layman. Later, for Option 2 (as posted in the answer above) it says `2.3.0 or later` which is much clearer. I lacked attention to detail in this instance.

Comment: And, being fairly new to using Portage, the word `masked` did not stick out to me. It is now obvious that extra effort is required to get that version, and therefore follow those directions.